# Skipped 451 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview

I know there are similar problems in here. But i tried the possible solutions and still having error.

I am creating a list view with image and text views. the path of the image is retrieved from database. Now i want to load the images in the rows of the list view. In my activity i am doing this in onCreate
Code snippet is

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
                Looper.prepare();
                adapter = new ViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cursor);
            }
    }).start();
```

in the Adapter class i am doing this

```
class ViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {

            new ImgAdapter_My_list(image,pic).execute();
 ....
           }
}
```

The ImgAdapter_My_list extends asynctask to lower the load on the main thread

```
public class ImgAdapter_My_list extends  AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap>       {

    private ImageView imv;
    private String path;

    public ImgAdapter_My_list(ImageView imv,String path) {
        this.imv = imv;
        this.path=path;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + path);

        if (file.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null && imv != null) {
            Log.d("test", "post exe  success");
            imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imv.setImageBitmap(result);
        } else {
            Log.d("test","result=" + String.valueOf(result == null)); //result is null here
            Log.d("test","imv=" + String.valueOf(imv == null));
            Log.d("test","fail");
            imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

And after all this i get too much work on main thread error. PLease help

Comment: Your code looks clean - meaning all intense work is in background. But I guess the problem is, that you are spawning a new AsyncTask for each row in the ListView. Maybe you should use only one Thread that serves all rows and which loads only one picture at a time (first row) and then the one for the second/next row? Maybe this helps: [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html).

Comment: And the run method is on the NON-UI thread but you are touching the UI (ViewAdapter) in that which can lead to this behaviour as well.

Comment: I personally like this way of loading data (from a database) into a ListView: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-populating-listview-from-sqlite-database-using-cursorloader-loadermanager-and-content-provider/

Comment: Matthias thanks i got your suggestion. but can you help me with the code changes ., as in how to start one thread only because i am making view in the bind view only ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing the `ViewAdapter` into it's own thread shouldn't be necessary.  And actually, in this case, since you want to do some processing on each row, I would abandon the use of a `CursorAdapter` altogether.  I find that the `CursorAdapter` is really only useful in cases where the data returned by the database is in a ready-to-"digest" form for the `ListView` (ie. raw text).

Instead, I would use the `AsyncTask` to load all of the data from the database and process it in one swoop, load the results into a custom object, then build an `ArrayAdapter` that utilizes the custom objects to display.

Custom class object:

```
public class ImageObject {
    private String text;
    private String path;
    private Bitmap image;

    public ImageObject(String text, String path) {
        this.text = text;
        this.path = path;
    }

    //Getters and setters for the class variables.
}
```

The workflow I picture would be as follows:

1. `AsyncTask` connects to database, runs query, and sifts through the
   results placing each row into an `ArrayList` of `ImageObjects`.
2. On each row, it executes the `File` code you have above, and places the `Bitmap` into the `ImageObject`.
3. `AsyncTask` returns the `ArrayList<ImageObject>`
4. The `ArrayList<ImageObjects>` is then passed into a custom
   `ArrayAdapter` and the data sits in it's final form, ready to be
   displayed.

Hopefully that makes sense, let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Hi, your answer is useful. But i am confused with the 3rd and 4th point.

Comment: i made a class of image objects , then in the doInBackground i did the database get value work  and made an array list out of the returned cursor.

Comment: please see the above post by me

Comment: So similar to how you extended CursorAdapter, there is a class called ArrayAdapter that has similar functionality for working with arrays instead of databases.